# Laravel 5 Modify Mass Assignment

Tags: laravel-5, mass-assignment

How I can change the fillable attribute of a model on the fly?

For example, I have User model with,
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password']

When updating the user, I want to exclude 'email' from mass assignment so that the email is not changed on update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass assignment doesn't mean all the field listed in `fillable` will be auto filled.

You still have control over what to save in the table.

So if you do:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->email = 'email@emails.com';
$user->save();
```

Only email will be saved in the example above while name and password remains the same